# Looking for recommendations on open-source Java instrument visualization components

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, open-source, widget

I am putting together an Java application that needs to display some basic lab instrument components.  For example, I'd like to display: a strip chart, oscilloscope-style trace, and a panel meter (galvanometer needle).  Rendering requirements are open (as long as the engine is free and generally available).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). We've implemented a couple of strip chart applications with it. Offhand I'm not sure about an oscilloscope type trace, you'd have to look into it. It does look like there is a meter-like [capability](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/DialPlotDemo2a.png).

Comment: Cool.  I had looked at JFreeChart before, but didn't see anything anything like "Strip Chart" or "Chart Recorder" in the API.  I see now that it is a "Dynamic Chart".  I also see the meter-like charts.  I'm thinking I might be able to hammer something into an oscilloscope trace with JFreeChart.  Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this myself so I cannot say how good it is but I came across these tools some time ago. [DART Visualization tools](http://www.itee.uq.edu.au/~eresearch/projects/dart/outcomes/visualization.php). They use an open source license. Maybe there is something in there to help you.